# How can I move directives from main.js into an external file Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-directives

I would like to have a clean main.js and for this I want to move the directives into an external file. That is, to do something like

```
//main.js
import directives from "./extensions-vue/directives";
app.directive(directives);
```

and in an external file

```
export default {
    myDirective: {
        mounted(el) {
            alert(el);
        },
    },
};
```

My version of course does not work, how to do it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define them in a separate file like :

```
export default {
    'alert': {
        mounted(el) {
            alert(el);
        },
    },
  'log': {
        mounted(el) {
            console.log(el);
        },
    },
};
```

then import them in main.js and loop through them to declare them globally :

```
//main.js
import directives from "./extensions-vue/directives";

Object.keys(directives).forEach(key=>{ //Object.keys(directives) gives ["alert","log"]

   app.directive(key,directives[key])
//directive name--^    ^-------directive definition

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Well they doesn't really offer a good option for it in the docs, I use it like this:

in directives/index.js:

```
export const focusDirective = {
  mounted(el) {
     el.focus();
 }};
```

in main.js:

```
import { focusDirective } from './directives'; // import all wanted directives
const app = createApp(App);
app.directive('focus', focusDirective );
```

I feel like its simpler and more intuitive then the other answer, But i'd prefer a way for my diretive file to register those directives globally without the need to handle it on main.js